# Zebra printer: printed images blurry

Tags: zebra-printers

My customer recently bought Zebra GK420t printers and wants to print barcodes with them. The barcodes are JPEG files with a resolution of 3000x5000 pixels. The DPI is 203x203 and the images are 1-bit.

The barcodes are printed in Firefox. Because the barcodes only need to be about 150x250 pixels, I included them this way in the HTML-page:

```
<img src="barcode.jpeg" width="250" height="150" />
```

UPS is doing this the same way with their labels to keep a good quality image. When I print the labels with a laser printer they just look fine. But when I print them with the Zebra printer they look blurry. I also tried printing it in full size with the Zebra printer and they just look fine then. Below are the results I scanned:

Zebra vs Laser:
[image]

Zebra fullsize:
http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/6259/zebra2r.jpg

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Why is the result on the Zebra printer blurry?

Comment: How are you sending the job to the Zebra printer? Using the ZDesigner driver?  Can you try scaling the image to 250x150 outside of firefox (using Gimp or something) and then try again? There might be a scaling issue in the ZDesigner driver

Comment: You may also check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641097/printing-to-zebra-printer-gives-faint-and-blurry-images

Answer (score 0):

Zebra printers have their own printing lanugage called ZPL. And ZPL has a wide range of barcode support you wont need to use jpg's for that. You could simple give the command for the specific barcode you want and what number or text it requires...but you need to study ZPL codes a bit its not super easy, but it will print better then what you showed here.